# How to encode a character in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, character-encoding

I am having problem regarding character there is multiple characters which is not displaying correctly and some are below.

This Mesícní výpisy is displaying like Mes�cn� v�pisy
This Týdenní prehled  is displaying T�denn� prehled

and my html form where i am having this problem

```
<form id="preferences_form" role="form" method="POST" novalidate action="{{ url('/preference') }}" class="mujucet-registration">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <h5>Nastavení zpráv</h5>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label  for="ch1">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="monthly" value="1" id="ch1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Mesícní výpisy
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label >
                    <input type="checkbox" name="weekly" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Týdenní prehled
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="tax_reviews" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Danové výpisy
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="quarterly" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Ctvrtletní výpisy
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="annually" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Rocní výpisy
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Novinky
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label class="border">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="direct_mail_reviews" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span> Chci výpisy zasílat také Poštou <span class="light">20 kc za výpis</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <h5>Kontaktní preference</h5>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="email" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Email
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="sms" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>SMS
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>                    </div>
```

I don't  know how its changed and how i can bring it to previous form this is annoying me and i am unable to solve this issue.

Here i need your help and it will be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome. Make sure your editor saves files as `utf-8`?

Answer (score 0):

Blade views do not automatically convert special characters to [html encoded characters](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref), you will have to do this yourself. The string in your view should therefor be the following:

```
<h5>Nastaven&iacute; zpr&aacute;v</h5>
```

You could however wrap the string in blade 'tags' and let blade convert the string like so:

```
<h5>{{ 'Nastavení zpráv' }}</h5>
```

Comment: Hm, I have no problems pasting "Mesícní výpisy" in a blade view and displaying it correctly.

Comment: Using “html encoded characters” is a very old-school way of going about this, should not be done this way in a project that is halfway current to begin with IMHO. That the template file was not saved in the proper character encoding is likely the source of the problem here.

Comment: @Jerodev its working when  i enter <h5>Nastaven&iacute; zpr&aacute;v</h5> but its working in blades templates?

Answer (score 0):

The e helper function will encode the HTML characters within a string value

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Htmlable;
class CustomHtmlable implements Htmlable
{
public function toHtml()
{
    return '<p>This is a value</p>';
}
}
// Create a new instance.
$instance = new CustomHtmlable;
// The value will still contain the HTML tags.
$returnValue = e($instance);
```